What genetic modifications could help plants survive in extreme environments like deserts or polar regions, based on current scientific knowledge?
My question is simple."I’ve been wondering—if you could genetically modify a plant species to survive in extreme environments like deserts or polar regions, what traits would you choose to prioritize, and why? I’m curious to hear your thoughts!"

Welcome Qalam. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help]. We can answer focused questions that have an answer that can be referenced - what you have here is a speculative question (covering more than one environment) that could devolve into opinion-based discussions. A better venue for this might be our [worldbuilding.se] site, but ensure to take their tour and read their help centre before posting so that your question is in-shape and on-topic.

For deserts, holding onto water and minimizing water loss, and for polar areas, slow growth, the ability to resist freezing and the ability to remain dormant for extended periods. If you check out vegetation from these areas it will mostly tend to conform to these traits.

"Extremophiles" also come to mind, perhaps they could develop chemosynthesis?
